# 構造体の中のポインタ変数をもつ構造体から各々のメンバに値を代入したい

Tags: c

```
struct Edge
{
    int distance;
    char to;
    struct Edge *next;
};

struct Node
{
    int visited;
    char name;
    int cost;
    struct node *from;
    struct Edge *edge;
    struct Node *next;
}; 

struct Node *p, *head, *edge;
p = malloc(sizeof(p));
head = malloc(sizeof(head));
edge = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

struct Nodeの中にある構造体struct Edge *edgeのtoに値を代入したく、
p->edge->to = 'X';
のように書いたのですが、エラーになってしまいます。
書き方を教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 書き間違いなのかどうか分かりませんが、`struct node *from;` => `struct Node *from;`, `struct Node *p, *head, *edge;` => `struct Node *p, *head; struct Edge *edge;`, `p = malloc(sizeof(p));` => `p = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`, `edge = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` => `p->edge = malloc(sizeof(struct Edge));` ではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> p = malloc(sizeof(p));

pは、ポインタなので、ポインタ分の領域しか確保されません。edgeの場合と同様に、structのサイズの確保が必要です。 また、p->edge とありますが、ここの edgeは、グローバル(structの外側)で宣言している edgeとは別物なので、領域の確保がされていません。

例えば、実際に使うところで、

```
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    p->edge = malloc(sizeof(struct Edge));
    p->edge->to = 'X';
```

のようにすべきです。

なお、後始末(free)も忘れないように。 (後始末、大変そうなパターン)

Comment: 回答が変わっていたので、見直し。
> _常に_元の投稿者に敬意を払う